# How to modify 2dsphere index without downtime for $geoNear queries?

Tags: mongodb

`$geoNear` queries both require a geospatial index and also require only one geospatial index.

From the docs:

https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/reference/operator/aggregation/geoNear/#behavior

> - $geoNear requires a geospatial index.
> - The $geoNear requires that a collection have at most only one 2d index and/or only one 2dsphere index.

If I need to make changes to an existing geospatial index on a production system with frequent (one every few seconds) `$geoNear` queries, how would I apply this change without downtime?

I'm using Mongo 3.4 if that matters, and could upgrade to 3.6 if that would make this easier.

Comment: Modifying a geo index generally means rebuilding the index (i.e. drop and recreate). What change are you making to your geo index and what type of deployment do you have (standalone, replica set, or sharded cluster)? If you need to modify a required index on a production system your most viable option would be a rolling rebuild as per [Build Indexes on Replica Sets](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/build-indexes-on-replica-sets/). Replica sets (or shards backed by replica sets) are generally required if you want to manage changes in production which would otherwise require downtime.

Comment: I'm adding fields and potentially reordering the fields in the index. We have a replica set. No sharding currently. We also are hosted in MongoDB Atlas if that makes any of this easier...looks like the docs assume we're hosting on our own. But, looks like this is doable because we use a replica set? Awesome, thanks :)

Comment: MongoDB Atlas (and other managed services) change the administrative options available since you intentionally do not have direct access to reconfigure the underlying `mongod` instances. Given this constraint you might have to: plan for downtime of the aggregation relying on the geo query, drop your geo index, and rebuild the index in the background with new options. If extended downtime of the geo/agg query isn't possible, an alternative approach might be: copy the collection, add the new geo index, then rename the current and new collection to effectively swap in the new replacement.

Comment: If you are on a paid MongoDB Atlas plan (M10 or above), I recommend you [file a MongoDB Atlas support issue](https://cloud.mongodb.com/support) to see if the support team has any other suggestions or ability to help you out further. Unfortunately this is a non-standard request and options are likely limited (and definitely limited in the case of free M0 or M2/M5 shared deployments).

Comment: Hmm, that's a bummer about Atlas. I could test this with a bit of time, but in case you know off hand, could I create the new index and then chain a dropIndex call upon completion of the creation? I believe that would only cause query errors during the duration of the drop, if I understand correctly. Thanks for all your advice. Feel free to post an answer that I can accept.

Comment: I just tested background build of a second 2dsphere index while running an aggregation query with a `$geoNear` stage on MongoDB 3.4.10. The aggregation query continues to run successfully until the background index build completes, at which point it throws the expected exception `"geoNear command failed: { ok: 0.0, errmsg: \"more than one 2dsphere index, not sure which to run geoNear on\"` until the second 2dsphere index is dropped. It looks like this is a viable workaround for your use case, although I haven't done any significant testing beyond a quick repro. I'll summarise for an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried this on MongoDB 4.2.x and it appears to no longer be an issue. I don't know in which version this issue was resolved/improved. I had two `2dsphere` indexes on the same collection and no queries were having issues.

According to the docs, this is still an issue, but only for `$geoNear` queries, and you can work around it by telling it which index to use:

> - If your collection has multiple 2dsphere index and/or multiple 2d
>   index, you must use the key option to specify the indexed field path
>   to use.
> - If you do not specify the key, you cannot have multiple
>   2dsphere index and/or multiple 2d index since without the key, index
>   selection among multiple 2d indexes or 2dsphere indexes is ambiguous.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/2dsphere/#geonear-and-geonear-restrictions